# Extend json by python by for loop

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, dictionary, aws-step-functions

I am working in aws step functions and I want to have 100 branches for multiple invokation.

```
erp_list = ['erp01', 'erp02'.....'erp99' ]
```

```
Json = {'a' : 'apple',
        'branches' : [
          {'erp' : 'erp01',
           'code' :'lambda01', 
            'type' : 'lambda'}
          ]
         }
```

LOOKING For ERP replace from list and different element for code.

```
{'a' : 'apple',
        'branches' : [
          {'erp' : 'erp01',
           'code' :'lambda1', 
            'type' : 'lambda'}, 
          
          {'erp' : 'erp002',
           'code' :'lambda2'
           'type' : 'lambda'}
        ] 
       }
```

Tried

```
for ERP in erp_list:
 val = re.sub('erp01',ERP, json)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension.

```
json = {
    'a': 'apple',
    'branches': [{'erp': e, 'code': 'lambda'} for e in erp_list]
}
```

Comment: if it works it's super cool..

Comment: is it possible to replace 1,2... in lambda as well.. like lambda 1 and lambda 2... so on.. Aws is not accepting same choice title